# Add Google Analytics e-commerce tracking to WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, woocommerce

I used two plugins trying to achieve sending purchase data to Google Analytics with no success.

I want, if possible, to add a new WordPress custom function to log and track all successful transfers along with the buyer's info. Keep in mind that I use various payment gateways so I can't depend on the Woo's "Thank you" page as there isn't always a redirection after the purchase.

My thought was utilizing the `woocommerce_thankyou` or `woocommerce_payment_complete` actions and hooks. Can you please propose a solution?

Useful resource: [Google Analytics Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce)

Thank you,
Giannis

Comment: I have written blog for this. Hope this will help: http://blog.rahuldadhich.com/enable-ecommerce-tracking-for-woocommerce/